# Cookie error after updating chrome driver - OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'invalid argument: invalid 'expiry'

Tags: c#, selenium, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

**Hi all, I am attempting to update to Chrome Driver version 89.0.4389.23 which matches the version of Chrome I am now using:**

[image]

****However, when executing tests I am getting the following error:**** `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'invalid argument: invalid 'expiry'`

[image]

**If I revert the Chrome Driver back to version 72.0.3626.69. It works!**

**I wondered if anyone knows why it is throwing this error and what a potential solution may be.**

**Thanks**

**##################### EDIT ######################**

**This is the cookie expiry value but I am not sure why it is 1/1/0001**

[image]

**I have set the expiry date of the cookie to tomorrow which can be seen as the value below but then I face this error**

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the value of `response.Cookies[0].Expires`?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I have edited the question to include the cookie expiry value. I am not sure why it would set it as 1/1/0001 or why this works ok with Chrome Driver 72.

Comment: 1/1/0001 of the default value for DateTime in C#. Sounds like you just need to set the cookie expiration date, and you're good.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I set the date to tomorrow but I am hitting another error now. I have updated the question with the details if you are happy to take a look. Thanks

Comment: Please do not post images of code, or images of exceptions. Include the code in your question as a code block. Add the exception and stack trace as well. At this point, you are facing a different question, so it might be better to post a new question with a [repro].